# What is the code when I want to show a @2x image in app

Tags: ios, image

Today when I search some information about `@1x @2x @3x`
something confuses me
are these only used as app icon? Because most messages always give me the example of the icon.
and If it can be used in app view, how is the code?
like this?

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"]];
```

Then, `iOS` will change `@1x and @2x` itself? OR I need to code like this:

```
#define deviceIsIPhone5 ([UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame.size.height == 568 ? YES : NO)
    if (deviceIsIPhone5) 
{
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background@2x.png"];
} 
else
{
    self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background.png"];
}
```

Comment: iOS does it internally. You don't need to care about it, just put the images in.

Comment: iPhone Autometically pick up which they have to display ,,, according to their resulation... you need not to worry about that,,,,if you are taking `UIImageView` than add `aspect-Ratio` constraints

Comment: Use Asset and put right image size.iOS will automatically handle @2x,@3x images as per the device resolution.

Comment: thank all of you  got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to think about @2x @3x.iOS automatically handles it.

All you need to care about is to put right size image into the right box(.xcassets) if you want to show image properly in all iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

no need to care about 2x,3x and png.
just enter image name only. ios will automatically check image to use according to screen dimensions.

```
self.backgroundImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"background"];
```